# NSClient++: Invalid return code -1073741502

Tags: nagios, nsclient++

I got a problem with NSClient++ (version 0.3.8.76).
I set up an external script handler, and it was working. 
But since some time it returns this, everytime i run the check:

```
No output available from command (cmd /c echo scripts\scriptname.ps1; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -).
```

It just stopped working in the middle of the night, without any interaction.

A look in the NSClient++ Logs reveals:

```
error:modules\CheckExternalScripts\CheckExternalScripts.cpp:188: The command (cmd) returned an invalid return code: -1073741502
```

Since then, this happens to every script i try to run. Nothing seems to work anymore.
Restarting the NSClient Service doesn't help, but when i run nsclient with the /test flag, it's working as intended.

Rebooting is difficult, as this machine has some productive services running.

The NSC.ini seems to be ok, since no changes were made since it was working, and the same configuration is also used on different hosts and working. Also nsclient++.exe /test works as it should.

I appreciate any help or hints on how to fix this problem. tia!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it stops working it sounds like a socket issue which is most likely fixed in 0.4.1/0.4.2
All in all 0.3.8 is very very old and an upgrade will fix many issues (including timeout issues and broken pipe issues, etc etc).

Comment: sorry for the late response. yes, an upgrade of nsclient fixed that issue.